# Find the LVM and VG name from Ansible inputting the Mount point name

Tags: installation, module, ansible, lvm

I'm trying to find if we have any options in setup or any combination of ansible modules to find the LVM / VG name if we give the mount point name as input to the playbook, please suggest if you have any options, as of now I can only see the only option in setup is to fetch the device name "device": "/dev/mapper/rhel-root", using the ansible_mounts.device. But to split the LV and VG name from the "/dev/mapper/rhel-root" is another challenge. Kindly suggest if any options.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually possible [since 2015](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/11762) through the `ansible_lvm` facts returned by `setup` and part of the `hardware` subset.

To get a result, you need to run `setup` as root and the lvm utilities must be installed on the target.

You can make a quick test on your local machine (if relevant, adapt to whatever target where you have privilege escalation rights):

```sh
ansible localhost -b -m setup \
  -a 'gather_subset=!all,!min,hardware' -a 'filter=ansible_lvm'
```

Here is an example output from the first test vm I could connect to:

```
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_lvm": {
            "lvs": {
                "docker_data": {
                    "size_g": "80.00",
                    "vg": "docker"
                },
                "root": {
                    "size_g": "16.45",
                    "vg": "system"
                },
                "swap": {
                    "size_g": "3.00",
                    "vg": "system"
                }
            },
            "pvs": {
                "/dev/sda2": {
                    "free_g": "0.05",
                    "size_g": "19.50",
                    "vg": "system"
                },
                "/dev/sdb": {
                    "free_g": "0",
                    "size_g": "80.00",
                    "vg": "docker"
                }
            },
            "vgs": {
                "docker": {
                    "free_g": "0",
                    "num_lvs": "1",
                    "num_pvs": "1",
                    "size_g": "80.00"
                },
                "system": {
                    "free_g": "0.05",
                    "num_lvs": "2",
                    "num_pvs": "1",
                    "size_g": "19.50"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be a very simple .yaml file, doing the same as what @Zeitounator suggested:

```yaml
---
- name: detect lvm setup
    setup:
        filter: "ansible_lvm"
        gather_subset: "!all,!min,hardware"
      register: lvm_facts
    - debug: var=lvm_facts
```